# Monitor loses signal after Ubuntu 16.0.4 i386 installation

Tags: server, 32-bit

I have a **Ubuntu 16.04 server** installation on a [fit-PC](http://www.fit-pc.com/) which is i386. The installation goes fine, no errors, but whenever I boot into Ubuntu, **my monitor loses its signal** and whatever I do, I cannot get it to work. 
I tried it with **CentOS 7** i386, **same problem**, multiple monitors, same problem. 
Funny thing is. I have another fit-PC, which is identical and runs **CentOS 6.9 i386 and I have no issues** when I plug it into the same monitor, so I'm a bit at a loss here.

These are the specs as far as I know:

```
CPU: Intel Athom (i386)
Hard Drive: 8 Gb
Video Input: HDMI
RAM: 1 Gb
```

I've tried everything, including turning it off and on again. Different HDMI cables, nothing. I've tried it on 2 monitors and made sure the right ones were connected and no, I couldn't ssh into it. 
Strange is, When I boot the machine, **you see the BIOS screen**, then it goes down a **list with the modules and processes it load**s, and then after that, **it goes black**

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0):

Have tried turning the monitor off and on? I have to do this with Ubuntu 18.04 and an Intel NUC.

And you sure the monitor is connected to the right port? If a fitpc has 2 HDMI ports make sure to try the other port as well.

Do both fitpc's have the same bios version and settings?

If you have SSH enabled, you could login and see what's in /var/log/syslog.

Comment: I've tried everything, including turning it off and on again. Different HDMI cables, nothing. I've tried it on 2 monitors and made sure the right ones were connected and no, I couldn't ssh into it. Strange is, When I boot the machine, you see the BIOS screen, then it goes down a list with the modules and processes it loads, and then after that, it goes black.